# Complex auto numbering in table MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have the table with three columns. First two columns have complex numbering.

I want to number elements of table like this:

```
| First Column | Second Column   |
__________________________________
| 1. bla       | 1.1. bla-bla    |
|              | 1.2. bla-bla    |

| 2. bla       | 2.1. bla-bla    |
|              | 2.2. bla-bla    |
| 3. bla       | 3.1. bla-bla    |
```

Is there a way to do it **automatically**?

Comment: This seems to be the result you want. But how does it look like before the wanted automatism starts? Do jou write "bla" in the first column and then it should be changed to "1. bla"? Shell the second column be filled automaticly afterwards?

Comment: Yes. The elements of table are located as on scheme. I want to add numbering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using styles. Create one new style for the first column and another for the second. (When I tested this, I called them First Column and Second Column, so I'll use those names in the rest of the answer.)

When you've created the styles, apply First Column to the text in the first column. Select some or all of that text and then use the Multilevel List button (in the Paragraph section of the Home tab) to define a new multilevel list and format it how you want it. With your numbered text selected, modify the First Column style to match the selection.

For the second column, again, select some of that text. Assign the same multilevel list style to it. Then, using the Multilevel List button, change the list level. You will then need to go back to Define New Multilevel list. Under Include Number From, select Level 1.

Now, just use that style for all the text in the appropriate tables, and you're good to go.

Comment: Impressive (that it is possible and you know it) :-)